# Compare two spark dataframes containing floating point numbers for Unittesting

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have to write unit tests to compare output from my code, for this I have to compare two pyspark dataframes containing floating point numbers.

When I try to compare them with assetEquals, it fails saying the corresponding values do not match, mostly a problem with floating point comparisons, I want to use something like np.isclose here but I am not sure how, because np.isclose doesn't for for my case. Consider the example below:

```
df1 =[
            {
                "customer_id": "1",
                "e0": 1.1,
                "e1": 2.2,
                "e2": 3.3,
                "e3": 0.0,
            }
        ]

df2 = [
            {
                "customer_id": "1",
                "e0": 1.100000000121,
                "e1": 2.1999999999012,
                "e2": 3.3,
                "e3": 0.0,
            }
       ]
assertEquals(df1, df2).
```

I want both these dfs to be compared at max 5th decimal point, but not sure how to do this.

Comment: You can round the Columns with Double Type and compare these dataframes.
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.round

you could as well use the in built function `except_all` (`except` for scala). It will fit your needs.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like

```
df1_rounded  = df1.withColumn("e0", func.round(df_1.e0,5)).withColumn("e1", func.round(df_1.e,5))...
df2_rounded  = df2.withColumn("e0", func.round(df_2.e0,5)).withColumn("e1", func.round(df_2.e,5))...
```

and then compare them.
E.g. you can compare them by checking that the intersection size of the df1 and df2 is the same as that of the df1 and df2.

Note that for them to be equal they need to have the same order if you just check for equals.